# How can I execute some commands locally while also executing a script remotely via ssh, without interrupting a connection?

Tags: bash, ssh, remote

I want to execute a script this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

# a ssh connection
ssh USER@HOST << EOF
COMMAND1
COMMAND2
COMMAND3
EOF

# here I should execute some commands locally
COMMAND4
COMMAND5


# here back to *the same* ssh connection
# how?
```

Is this possible? And how, if yes?

Comment: Are you aware of how to do ssh connection sharing?

Answer (score 0):

From `man ssh` the `~` followed by `^Z` will suspend the session, returning you to the local host. Run your commands, then enter `fg` to return to the ssh session.